# is possible allow a user to select only one checkbox (bootstrap checkbox-x)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I'm working with bootstrap checkbox-x plugin : https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-checkbox-x

How can I only allow a user to select only one checkbox?

Option 1

```
          <div class="col-md-12 has-success bottom-10 no-padding-left">
              <input class="form-control bottom-15" id="check-2" type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox-x" data-size="sm" data-three-state="false">
              <label class="cbx-label" for="check-2">Option 2 </label>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-12 has-success bottom-10 no-padding-left">
              <input class="form-control bottom-15" id="check-3" type="checkbox"  data-toggle="checkbox-x" data-size="sm" data-three-state="false">
              <label class="cbx-label" for="check-3">Option 3 </label>
          </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you want a radio control, not a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

True you could and probably should use a radio input field, but if you really would like to use the check box you can. You can gather all the check-boxes that you are targeting.

```
var chkBox = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
```

Then put a click event listener on it to fire once the check-box is clicked. It then will disable all the other check-boxes that are in the ones that you collected / targeted.

```
$(chkBox).on('click', function(){
    if ( $(this).prop( "checked") ) {
        $(this).siblings().prop( "disabled", true);
    } else {
        $(this).siblings().prop( "disabled", false);
    }
});
```

I added an else statement that will toggle the check-box state. You can remove it if you just want to disable them.